# When do we need to create an object with "new" and when can we just declare and assign value to it?

Tags: c#

More specifically in a LINQ to Entities query:

```
List<string> myResult = (from myTable do some joins...blah).ToList();
if(myResuly.Any())
{
 // Foo
}
```

My question is how do we know if we can use

```
List<string> myResult = (from myTable do some joins...blah).ToList();
```

or we should use:

```
List<string> myResult = new List<string>();
 myResult = (from myTable do some joins...blah).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148594/join-declaration-and-assignment-or-not-to-join-that-is-the-question

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to why you are confused. In the second example you create `myResult` and assign that to a new list. On the next line you then assign your variable to a different list. What is the point of the first assignment?

Comment: guys, it's a newbie question (see the username?).  calm down and help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a function on the right side of the `=` that is generating the value, you don't need `new`.  In your 3rd example, the list you `new` is immediately thrown away and the one returned by ToList() is used in it's place

Comment: thanks, in my head it was like objects should always be created with "new" before we start working with them.

Comment: @DevWannaBe The important point here is you've got the variable `myResult`, then you have the actual object which you assign to it. The `new` has to do with how you create the actual object, it has nothing to do with initializing the variable. Conceptually what happens to the left and right of that `=`-sign is very different.

Answer (score 1):

We should *never use* (though it's *safe*) the code like that:

```
  List<string> myResult = new List<string>();
  myResult = ... // myResult is reassinged here and "new List<string>()" just lost
```

since you're just creating *useless* `List<string>` instance. Put instead

```
  List<string> myResult = WhatEver(...).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can already get the list why waste an extra line of code?

```
List<string> myResult = new List<string>();
```

The whole idea of initializing your list, is that you don't already have one that you can stock in 'myResult'.

Imagine trying to access your list that you haven't initialized yet.